# Redirect BaseHTTPServer stdout to logging

Tags: python, logging

I wrote a quick webserver using BaseHTTPServer, and it's working nicely, so now I'm trying to implement logging, and I noticed, hey, seems like BaseHTTPServer already has some logging information that it spits out to the stdout, is there a way to implement my logging to also include this stdout.

i.e. Have logging record all information from the stdout.

Note: I am not explicitly printing anything to the console window, when a GET request is made, BaseHTTPServer handles printing this to the console.

Example:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [02/May/2014 20:51:52] "GET /postTest.html HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/May/2014 20:51:52] "GET /assets/foundation.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/May/2014 20:51:52] "GET /assets/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/May/2014 20:51:57] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/May/2014 20:51:57] "GET /assets/foundation.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/May/2014 20:51:57] "GET /assets/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [BaseHTTPServer documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/basehttpserver.html#BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler.log_message), you can override the `log_message` method to do this. By default, it just writes to stderr, but you can make it write to your logger instead (or have it write to both).

Comment: Ah so it seems like I have to overwrite the method?

Comment: Yep, that seems like your best option (to me, at least).